# Can one dynamically set column data of a %rowtype object based on data in cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table of default values which contain the column name and the default value. Is there a way in PL/SQL to set the associated column based on the value in the defaults table cursor?

My real world case has 60 fields and is obviously a bit more complex than the structures below which works but becomes tedious to maintain.

```
create table test_defaults (default_type varchar2(20), column_name varchar2(30), column_value varchar2(10));
insert into test_defaults values ('homo sapien','leg_count', '2');
insert into test_defaults values ('homo sapien','animal_class', 'mammal');
insert into test_defaults values ('homo sapien','arm_count', '2');

insert into test_defaults values ('koi','leg_count', '0');
insert into test_defaults values ('koi','animal_class', 'fish');
insert into test_defaults values ('koi','arm_count', '0');

insert into test_defaults values ('horse','leg_count', '4');
insert into test_defaults values ('horse','animal_class', 'mammal');
insert into test_defaults values ('horse','arm_count', '0');
commit;

drop table my_critters;
create table my_critters(my_type varchar2(20),leg_count varchar2(10),animal_class varchar2(10),arm_count varchar2(10));

create or replace procedure build_defaults(critter_type varchar2)
as
  critter_rec my_critters%rowtype;
  cursor curs_defaults
  is
    select * from test_defaults where default_type = critter_type;
begin
  for default_rec in curs_defaults
  loop
    critter_rec := null;
    case default_rec.column_name
      when 'leg_count'
      then critter_rec.leg_count := default_rec.column_value;
      when 'animal_class'
      then critter_rec.animal_class := default_rec.column_value;
      when 'arm_count'
      then critter_rec.arm_count := default_rec.column_value;
    end case;  
    critter_rec.my_type := critter_type;
  end loop;
  insert into my_critters values critter_rec;
end;
```

What I would like is a simple way to assign the value to the field such as;

```
critter_rec[default_rec.column_name] := default_rec.column_value;
```

When last I looked at Oracle PL/SQL I could not find any support for this. I was hoping one of the newer versions might support it. My DB version is 19.11.

EDIT:

This routine is part of a much larger routine which works on a table which has over 300 columns. About 90 columns have defaults set by the defaults routine. About 60 of those are set from a table described above. The rest are set using discrete logic.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code? I would assume with [DBMS_SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS058) it should be possible. Perhaps you only need to make the `INSERT` as dynamic SQL

Comment: execute immediate

Comment: The purpose of the code is to set default values for a row, prior to inserting, or updating.  I will put a bit more details in the an EDIT to the post.

Answer (score -1):

As a frame challenge, don't use cursors or record types, use a single `INSERT ... SELECT` statement with a `PIVOT`:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE build_defaults(
  critter_type MY_CRITTERS.MY_TYPE%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO my_critters(my_type, leg_count, animal_class, arm_count)
  SELECT default_type, leg_count, animal_class, arm_count
  FROM   test_defaults
  PIVOT (
    MAX(column_value)
    FOR column_name IN (
      'leg_count'    AS leg_count,
      'animal_class' AS animal_class,
      'arm_count'    AS arm_count
    )
  )
  WHERE  default_type = critter_type;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9be3b2841d60a0a0b80366fc3a0db867)*

Comment: The use of the pivot is interesting. However my EDIT which I added about 23 hours ago and seems to have been deleted explained the actual table I am modifying has > 300 fields of which only 60 are to be "defaulted" using this routine.